# While loop not ending despite fulfilling conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I've structured a code to preform a simple task of taking in a username and password, checking they meet conditions and either repeating the process if they are incorrect or stopping the program if it is correct. However the while loop won't stop and the program keeps running. I've inserted the code below. How do I get the while loop to stop when the condition is fulfilled?

```
def loginConfirmation(user1,user2,pass1,pass2,confirm1,confirm2): 
  if len(user1) > 6:                           
      confirm1 = confirm1 + 1
  else:
      print("Invalid username Player 1")
  if len(user2) > 6:
      confirm2 = confirm2 + 1
  else:
      print("Invalid username Player 2")
  if pass1 == ("password"):                     
      confirm1 = confirm1 + 1
    else:
      print("invalid passsword Player 1")
  if pass2 == ("password"):
      confirm2 = confirm2 + 1
  else:
      print("Invalid passsword Player 2")
  confirmation = confirm1 + confirm2
  return confirmation

confirmation = 0
confirm1 = 0
confirm2 = 0

while confirmation != 4:
     print("Please enter your details below. Usernames must be at least six letters long.")
     user1 = input("Player 1, enter your username: ")
     pass1 = input("Player 1, enter your password: ")
     user2 = input("Player 2, enter your username: ")
     pass2 = input("Player 2, enter your password: ")
     loginConfirmation (user1,user2,pass1,pass2,confirm1,confirm2)
```

Comment: You don't ever assign the output of ```loginConfirmation``` to confirmation. Try  ```confirmation=loginConfirmation (user1,user2,pass1,pass2,confirm1,confirm2)```

Comment: (Questions are not closed here when they are answered. They are closed only if they are regarded as off-topic or unanswerable).

Comment: I'm aware the topic is not closed persay. I'm just making it clear that the issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign to your variable `confirmation` the return value of your function `loginConfirmation` in order to break the while-loop.

In the given code, the value of your variable `confirmation` is always 0 and thus the breaking condition of your while-loop is never met.

Update your code with the following:

```
def loginConfirmation(user1,user2,pass1,pass2,confirm1,confirm2): 
  if len(user1) > 6:                           
      confirm1 = confirm1 + 1
  else:
      print("Invalid username Player 1")
  if len(user2) > 6:
      confirm2 = confirm2 + 1
  else:
      print("Invalid username Player 2")
  if pass1 == ("password"):                     
      confirm1 = confirm1 + 1
    else:
      print("invalid passsword Player 1")
  if pass2 == ("password"):
      confirm2 = confirm2 + 1
  else:
      print("Invalid passsword Player 2")
  confirmation = confirm1 + confirm2
  return confirmation

confirmation = 0
confirm1 = 0
confirm2 = 0

while confirmation != 4:
     print("Please enter your details below. Usernames must be at least six letters long.")
     user1 = input("Player 1, enter your username: ")
     pass1 = input("Player 1, enter your password: ")
     user2 = input("Player 2, enter your username: ")
     pass2 = input("Player 2, enter your password: ")
     confirmation = loginConfirmation (user1,user2,pass1,pass2,confirm1,confirm2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to rearrange the code a little bit, try this code :

```
confirmation = 0
while confirmation != 4:
    confirm1 = 0
    confirm2 = 0
    print("Please enter your details below. Usernames must be at least six letters long.")
    user1 = input("Player 1, enter your username: ")
    pass1 = input("Player 1, enter your password: ")
    user2 = input("Player 2, enter your username: ")
    pass2 = input("Player 2, enter your password: ")
    confirmation = loginConfirmation (user1,user2,pass1,pass2,confirm1,confirm2)
```

NB :

1- the two variables confirm1 and confirm2 must reset to zero after each while calls

2- you have to assign the output value of your function 'loginConfirmation' to the confirmation variable